# FreeBSD RAID rebuild by data center, now data in /var/logs and /var/db/mysql is *gone*, OH NO!

Tags: raid, freebsd

OK, our data center did a RAID rebuild (and possibly some other stuff) on our server overnight. Something failed at some point, I checked on things this morning, and it appears as if the /var partition has been entirely wiped and brought back to a default install state.

i.e., everything we had in /var/logs is *gone* and everything we had in /var/db/mysql is *gone*, it's as if that stuff has been wiped out and replaced by a default install of FreeBSD (i.e. minimal logs, no stored .gzip logs, no more databases, etc.) BAD, REALLY BAD!

Actually, looking at it more, before if I did a "df -h" I'd see a /var partition. Now, I don't see it anymore. But I *can* get to /var... it just doesn't show up in "df -h". I *do* see an entry in /etc/fstab for /var.

I have pretty much no idea what they did. I'm waiting to hear from them. So I realize that this is a somewhat unanswerable question. I'm just looking for ideas on what I can check/what might have happened, etc. until I get more details from the data center about what they actually did.

In the meantime, can anyone propose a theory for where the data in /var might have gone... and how I can check if it still exists somewhere?

**EDIT** We're on the right track, thanks guys!

[kp@afekan /var/log]$ sudo tail -n 10 /var/log/dmesg.today

```
SMP: AP CPU #2 Launched!
SMP: AP CPU #3 Launched!
Trying to mount root from ufs:/dev/mfid0s1a
WARNING: /tmp was not properly dismounted
/tmp: mount pending error: blocks 24 files 0
WARNING: /usr was not properly dismounted
WARNING: R/W mount of /var denied.  Filesystem is not clean - run fsck
WARNING: R/W mount of /var denied.  Filesystem is not clean - run fsck
bce0: link state changed to UP
bce1: link state changed to UP
```

**They're working on it!**

**FIXED!** Problem solved, /var never got mounted, needed to be fsck'd. Thanks guys!

Comment: Now would be a good time to think about setting up some backups.

Comment: Oh we always have backups, and *lots* of them. :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `/var` partition isn't mounted. Probably there was an old, default install in `/var`; later on they might have added another volume and mounted it over.

Do ask them to check if every volume has been properly mounted; check `/etc/fstab` for the exact name/slice.

Also, it is also very likely that your current `var` partition has been created at system startup by the various daemons which, since they could not find their own directories, decided to create /var/log, /var/tmp, etc.

Say hi to the folks in the data centre :P

Answer (score 4):

Please show the output of  the following three commands:

```
# cat /etc/fstab
# mount 
# df -kh
```

It's possible that they have not mounted /var from /etc/fstab for whatever reason and it's living on your root directory.